# Toggling bootstrap tabs with a close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering how I can close a current tab in Twitter Bootstrap either by clicking on the active tab button or through a 'close' button. In other words, I want to know how to remove the 'active' class from:

1. Active tab button
2. Active tab pane

The user flow would be as follows:

1. All tabs unselected to start with
2. User clicks on a tab and relevant tab pane opens
3. User clicks on same tab button to close.
4. All tabs are closed.

A tab pane would look something like this:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade active" id="tab01">
          Tab content #01
          <a>Close Me</a>
</div><!-- /#tab01 -->
```

Hope this makes sense and appreciate the help!!

JS Fiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/dru_rustin/8Bw4z/

Comment: post a fiddle of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm not being able to demonstrate it in jsfiddle because of some post request issues.

1. Add an id to button close. And append a new HTML element for unfocus button.
   your code will be like this.

   ```
   <div id="configuration-panel" class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="tab01">Tab content #01 
   <a href="target" class="btn btn-primary" id="closetab">Close active tab</a>
   </div>

   <!-- /#tab01 -->
   ```
2. Append css

   ```
   #blur-hack {
       position: absolute;
       opacity: 0;
   }
   ```
3. Append Javascript

   ```
   $('#closetab').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#tab1').css("display", "none");
       $('#ur-hack').focus();
   });
   ```